# How can I detect collision in pygame while using colliderect() to make an object disappear without using sprites?

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection

I have two classes that both create squares. One that puts squares randomly in the window and another that the user can control. I need to detect collision between them but I keep getting an error that the I need a rect style object when I use the colliderect() function. I am pretty sure my drawings are rects but I might be wrong.

I tried using the win.blit method to use draw my rects but I cannot make that work and need some help

```
import random

import pygame

pygame.init() # initialize pygame managers



# create a window 

w = 600

h = 600

win = pygame.display.set_mode((w,h)) # define window variable

# pygame.display.set_caption("Read carefully.") 





#global variables 

WHITE = (255,255,255) # some handy RGB values

BLACK = (0,0,0)

YELLOW = (255, 186, 8)

x = random.randint(0,600)

y = random.randint(0,600)



#======================== Variables & functions ===================================================

#where we will create our class

    #attributes of our class defining our object 


def main():
    class Enemy1():

        color: str

        radius: int

        x: int

        y: int



        def __init__(self, color, radius, x=100, y=100):

            self.color = color

            self.radius = radius

            self.x= x

            self.y = y

            self.w = 50

            self.h = 50

            self.appear = True

            self.red = pygame.draw.rect(win,self.color,(self.y,self.x,self.w,self.h))



        def move_rect(self):

            if self.appear == True:

                self.red = pygame.draw.rect(win,self.color,(self.y,self.x,self.w,self.h))

        def collide(self):
            if (self.appear):
                if self.red.colliderect(self):
                    self.appear = False






    class Player():

        def __init__(self):

            self.y = 300

            self.x= 300

            self.w = 100

            self.h = 100

            self.color = WHITE

            self.appear = True

            self.circle = pygame.draw.rect(win,self.color,(self.x,self.y,self.w,self.h))



        def spawn(self):

            if self.appear == True:

                self.circle = pygame.draw.rect(win,self.color,(self.x,self.y,self.w,self.h))



        def keyPress(self, event, step= 20, up=pygame.K_UP, down=pygame.K_DOWN, left=pygame.K_LEFT, right=pygame.K_RIGHT):

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

                if event.key == up:

                    self.y -= step

                elif event.key == down:

                    self.y += step

                elif event.key == left:

                    self.x -= step

                elif event.key == right:

                    self.x += step                

       

            

    #creating a player

    player = Player()

    red = Enemy1((229,190,237), 20, 200, 150) # creating an enemy 1

    small = Enemy1((124,144,219), 15, 30, 130) # creating an enemy 2

    circle = Enemy1((115,107,146), 25, 150, 50) # creating an enemy 3

    #================================ Animation loop ===================================================

    # start run function def here

    running = True

    clock = pygame.time.Clock() # for framerate timing

    #starting the animation loop

    while running:

        win.fill(BLACK)

        #================== Your animation tasks ================

        # call functions, increment values

        player.spawn()

        red.move_rect()

        small.move_rect()

        



        for event in pygame.event.get():

            player.keyPress(event)
            
        #================== Interactinos ================

        # This loop allows windows when exit is clicked.

        # Do not change, remove or augment this loop...yet.
        # stop conditional would go here 

        #player.collide(red.move_rect)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:

                running = False # stops animation

                pygame.quit() # stops running code & closes window

        #================== Animation control ===================

        pygame.display.update()

        clock.tick(60) # framerate in fps (30-60 is typical)

main()

# pygame.display.quit() # uncomment to automatically close window at end of animation
```

Comment: Are you going to add some code to the question?   Because of the error message, the code is almost certainly *not* using the correct sort of `pygame.Rect`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do have a rectangle, but it's not a [PyGame Rect](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html).  The collision functions can *only* be used with a Rect.

The Rect is really handy.  The code doesn't need to store x, y, w, h ... all these can be put into a Rect:

```
class Player():
    def __init__(self):
        self.rect   = pygame.Rect( 300, 300, 100, 100 )
        self.color  = WHITE
        self.appear = True
```

If ever you do want access to the x, y, width, height - these are all still available from the Rect:  `self.rect.x`, `self.rect.height`, etc.

This makes the collision checking simple:

```
class Player():
    # ...

    def collidesWith( self, other_rect ):
        collides = self.rect.colliderect( other_rect )    #<<-- HERE
        if ( collides ):
            print( "Player collides" )
        return collides
```

I made a similar change to the Enemy class.  This allows the code to make a list of all Enemy1 objects, then iterate through them, testing for collisions:

```
enemies = [ red, small, circle ]

# ...

while running:

    # check for collision with every enemy
    for enemy in enemies:
        enemy.collidesWith( player.rect )
```

Full code:

```
import random

import pygame

pygame.init() # initialize pygame managers



# create a window 
w = 600
h = 600
win = pygame.display.set_mode((w,h)) # define window variable

# pygame.display.set_caption("Read carefully.") 


#global variables 
WHITE = (255,255,255) # some handy RGB values
BLACK = (0,0,0)
YELLOW = (255, 186, 8)
x = random.randint(0,600)
y = random.randint(0,600)

#======================== Variables & functions ===================

#where we will create our class

    #attributes of our class defining our object 


def main():
    class Enemy1():
        color: str
        radius: int
        x: int
        y: int

        def __init__(self, color, radius, x=100, y=100):
            self.color = color
            self.radius = radius
            self.rect = pygame.Rect( x, y, 50, 50 )
            self.appear = True

        def move_rect(self):
            if self.appear == True:
                pygame.draw.rect( win, self.color, self.rect )

        def collidesWith( self, other_rect ):
            collides = self.rect.colliderect( other_rect )
            if (self.appear):
                if collides:
                    print( "Enemy1 collides" )
                    self.appear = False
            return collides;


    class Player():

        def __init__(self):
            self.rect = pygame.Rect( 300, 300, 100, 100 )
            self.color = WHITE
            self.appear = True

        def spawn(self):
            if self.appear == True:
                self.circle = pygame.draw.rect( win, self.color, self.rect )


        def collidesWith( self, other_rect ):
            collides = self.rect.colliderect( other_rect )
            if ( collides ):
                print( "Player collides" )
            return collides

        def keyPress(self, event, step= 20, up=pygame.K_UP, down=pygame.K_DOWN, left=pygame.K_LEFT, right=pygame.K_RIGHT):
            used_event = False
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == up:
                    self.rect.y -= step
                    used_event = True

                elif event.key == down:
                    self.rect.y += step
                    used_event = True

                elif event.key == left:
                    self.rect.x -= step
                    used_event = True

                elif event.key == right:
                    self.rect.x += step                
                    used_event = True

            return used_event
       

            

    #creating a player
    player = Player()
    red = Enemy1((229,190,237), 20, 200, 150) # creating an enemy 1
    small = Enemy1((124,144,219), 15, 30, 130) # creating an enemy 2
    circle = Enemy1((115,107,146), 25, 150, 50) # creating an enemy 3

    enemies = [ red, small, circle ]

    #================================ Animation loop ====================

    # start run function def here

    running = True
    clock = pygame.time.Clock() # for framerate timing

    #starting the animation loop
    while running:
        win.fill(BLACK)

        #================== Your animation tasks ================
        # call functions, increment values

        player.spawn()
        red.move_rect()
        small.move_rect()

        
        #================== Interactinos ================
        # This loop allows windows when exit is clicked.
        # Do not change, remove or augment this loop...yet.
        # stop conditional would go here 

        # check for collision with every enemy
        for enemy in enemies:
            enemy.collidesWith( player.rect )

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False # stops animation

            elif player.keyPress(event):
                pass   # player used event

        #================== Animation control ===================

        pygame.display.update()

        clock.tick(60) # framerate in fps (30-60 is typical)

main()
pygame.quit() # stops running code & closes window
```

There was also a little bug in handling the Window events, I fixed this.